# Uploading files from mapper in AWS EMR cluster to S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have an existing map reduce job running on AWS EMR, which handles billion of lines of logs and do some computations to form (key, value) pair from mapper. These computations are very time consuming and I need to use the output of some intermediate step of these computations in some other map reduce job. So, I want to tap computation's output and upload to s3, without affecting existing job (i.e. without changing current mapper or reducer). Before upload, I will first gather these lines in a local temporary file and once file becomes sufficiently large, I will upload this file to s3.

The problem is - Unlike reducer, Mapper can't have sorted data based on key. How do I devise unique filenames for s3 for uploading data from different mappers, so that there will not be any filename conflict?

I am using Java. Problem can also be solved if there is a way to get mapper cluster ID or generate random no. unique to all mappers (which I don't know how to do?)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the task attempt ID for the currently running Hadoop task and that would be unique across all mappers and thus could be used as filenames. Following method will get you the attempt id:

```
public static String getAttemptId(Configuration conf) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
       if (conf == null) {
           throw new NullPointerException("conf is null");
       }

       String taskId = conf.get("mapred.task.id");
       if (taskId == null) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Configutaion does not contain the property mapred.task.id");
       }

       String[] parts = taskId.split("_");
       if (parts.length != 6 ||
               !parts[0].equals("attempt") ||
               (!"m".equals(parts[3]) && !"r".equals(parts[3]))) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("TaskAttemptId string : " + taskId + " is not properly formed");
       }

       return parts[4] + "-" + parts[5];
   }
```